# Pairwise substration table

Tags: r, pairwise

My dataset looks like this:

```
Col1 Col2
A     2
B     5
C     1
D     4
```

I would like to substract rows from Col2 so that the final output looks like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
A   0  -3   1  -2
B   3   0   4   1
C  -1  -4   0  -3
D   2  -1   3   0
```

I would appreciate some help as I am struggling formatting the results into a pairwise comparison table.

Comment: Are you looking for `outer()` ? Is your *dataset* a dataframe?

Comment: I am not aware of that function but after taking a quick look I see that it could work

Comment: if you could use `dist` that would be more efficient as well

Answer (score 2):

Using outer is definitely a good option. For instance:

```
x2 <- 1:4; names(x2) <- c("A","B","C","D")
x3 <- 1:4; names(x3) <- c("A","B","C","D")

outer(x2,x3, "-")

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
A    0   -1   -2   -3
B    1    0   -1   -2
C    2    1    0   -1
D    3    2    1    0
```

Thanks @jogo for the suggestion

Comment: `outer(x2, x2, '-')`